# Updating Civicrm Activities with Drupal Webforms

Tags: activities

We've been using Drupal webforms to create and update activities for contacts in Civicrm. 
Ever since we updated to civicrm 4.6.18 (from 4.6.10), When the webform is submitted which is supposed to update a civicrm activity, it creates a new activity instead with a random date and a random contact as the "added by" name. 
I've tested this on another site running 4.6.18 and the error only happens on my current site. I've disabled all the extensions and the error remains...

I enabled the date field in the Webform and set it to "now". When I enable "Update Existing Activity" It sets the date for may 23 2016. If I leave it disabled, the date field is set for today.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

I'm at a lost where to look... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an error that appeared with the Webform_Civicrm Module once updated Civicrm 4.6.18.
The reason I wasn't able to reproduce this error on my second site is because I didn't have the data needed to produce the error. 
Issue was opened here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2759099

Comment: yikes - that looks like a nasty bug